# getting second json object from url

Tags: java, json

a url is giving me output in json format. 
the problem is, the first object, always comes as NULL. 
is there a way to ignore first object and to process from second one ?

```
    {"result":[]} // first object

    {"result":[{"a":[{"t":"2","c":1},{"t":"3"}],"f":5}],"r":0}
```

i am getting these by

```
    while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(decodedString);
    }
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, then yes. The obvious way would be like this -

```
 in.readLine(); // <-- discard first line.
 while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(decodedString);
 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked.
solution was so simple.... may be i should go to sleep now....